# What are the solutions for storing secret data in an android application?

Tags: android, local-storage

What are the solutions for storing secret data in an android application so that it is not erased when the cache or application data is cleared?

Comment: In the application? Or somewhere on the device?

Comment: @blackapps I am considering all options. Perhaps there is an option not to clear the local database table?

Comment: One cannot store data in an application at runtime. That is no option.

Comment: @blackapps that is not the task. I have secret data (some api keys) that I want to keep in the application in case the user clears the cache. It is not safe to store them in a json file

Comment: If your keys are in the application then they are not in the cache or on device storage. So no cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Keystore** and **Cipher** for that to encrypt or decrypt your secret data. It will store your data in **TEE** that is a piece of hardware separated from Android OS.

It will also protect your data from rooting the device.

Update on Your comment:

If You have a server, then I would recommend you to store **API-key** there. Because it's the fastest secret way of getting it.